# Import Error, No Module named formats

Tags: python, django, leaflet, geojson

This is the error I get! I'm guessing I'm missing a module named formats? I'm very new to installations with django. So bear with me. Previously I had gotten error that vectorformat.formats module was missing. So I did sudo pip install vectorformats. This lead to the error I have now. See below:

```
from vectorformats.formats import django, geojson
ImportError: No module named formats
```

Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:
No module named formats
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/leaflet_storage/views.py in , line 25
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from vectorformats.Formats import ...`

note the uppercase 'F'

[documentation here](http://pythonhosted.org/vectorformats/formats/Django.html)

you'll have the same error message with `django` and `geojson`

Comment: You're wellcome. If you want to avoid downvotings you're wellcome to check the documentation before posting questions here This was a really easy one, and I don't have any idea what vectorformats is all about... Good luck!

Comment: I've noticed GPX is not in the documentation. I unfortunately have no idea how to import GPX when its not supported...:/
So thats a bit of a problem..

Comment: open an interactive python shell (or ipython shell) and use some introspection methods, like `dir(vectorformats)`, `help('vectorformats')`, autocompletion (not enabled by default in the python interactive shell)...